# Sequelize migration without file

Tags: node.js, database-migration, sequelize.js

Is there a way to use the sequelize migrator without the specified file? I would like to add/remove a column in my postgre database without using adding a file and using only custom method in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted an issue on [github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2457#issuecomment-59897329), and they responded quickly.